# React jQuery(this) selector is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, frontend

I should find parent div and closest label to clicked input and doing selection with jQuery. Although all scripts written without `$(this)` is working properly, but my following code is not working.

```
class LoginReg extends Component {
    render() {
        function MinimizeLabel(){
            $(this).closest(".Reg-fields").css("border-bottom", "2px solid #f99");
            $(this).closest("label").css("top", "-15px").css("font-size", ".7em").css("transition", ".3s ease-out");
        }

        return (
            <div>
              <div className="custom-container">
                <div className="Reg-fields">
                  <input type="email" onClick={MinimizeLabel}/>
                  <label>Email</label>
                </div>
              </div>
         );
}
```

Comment: This is completely wrong. Why do you use `JQuery` with `React`? If you use `React` then it's better to achieve that functionality by `React`.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh but how ?

Comment: Well, I can teach `React` to you. There is a documentation, there are a lot of resources on the internet. There is a set of concepts that you need to understand.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh you are so funny, man, I'm dying

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`this` points to React component instance and not the input element. You can achieve this using `event.target`

```js
class LoginReg extends Component {
    render() {
        function minimizeLabel(event){
            $(event.target).closest(".Reg-fields").css("border-bottom", "2px solid #f99");
            $(event.target).closest("label").css("top", "-15px").css("font-size", ".7em").css("transition", ".3s ease-out");
        }

        return (
            <div>
              <div className="custom-container">
                <div className="Reg-fields">
                  <input type="email" onClick={minimizeLabel}/>
                  <label>Email</label>
                </div>
              </div>
         );
}
```

Comment: @srvqaqa Most welcome, kindly mark the correct answer